# JSF composite button reinitiliazes view scoped managed bean

Tags: jsf, listener, composite-component

As soon as a composite which encapsulates a commandButton is included in my .xhtml, the viewscoped bean is reinitialized no matter which commandButton is used. Is my composite wrong? Please let me know because I realy would like to use composites for my buttons.
Simplyfied testcase:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class Test implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 123456L;
private static int i = 0;
private int counter;
private String table;
private transient DataModel<String> model;

@PostConstruct
public void test() {
    System.out.println(".......... PostConstruct");
    i++;
    List<String> modelData = new ArrayList<String>();
    modelData.add("hello");
    modelData.add("world");
    model = new ListDataModel<String>(modelData);
}


public int getCounter() {
    return counter;
}

public String getTable() {
    return table;
}

public DataModel<String> getModel() {
    return model;
}

public void tableListener() {
    String data = model.getRowData();
    table = data.toUpperCase();
}
```

}

No matter which button is clicked (2nd or 3th column), the postConstruct method is called over and over again

```
    <h:form>
        <h:dataTable style="width: 40em" var="line" value="#{test.model}">
            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">string</f:facet>
                #{line}
            </h:column>
            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">actie...1</f:facet>
                <h:commandButton value="toUpper" immediate="true"  >
                    <f:ajax event="click" execute="@form" render=":testTable" listener="#{test.tableListener}" />
                </h:commandButton>
            </h:column>
            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">actie...2</f:facet>
                <cmp:rowAction managedBean="#{test}" label="button" listener="tableListener"
                               tooltip="test via composite" img="stop.png" render=":testTable"/>
            </h:column>
        </h:dataTable>
    </h:form>
```

As soon as the last column (header actie...2) is removed, then the @PostConstruct is called only once, as expected.
Why does the presence of my composite forces to reinitialize the viewscoped bean? What's wrong with my composite, it works, but it shouldn't reinitialize the managed bean:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:cc="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

<!-- INTERFACE -->
<cc:interface>
    <cc:attribute name="label" required="true"/>
    <cc:attribute name="render"/>
    <cc:attribute name="tooltip"/>
    <cc:attribute name="img"/>
    <cc:attribute name="listener" required="true"/>
    <cc:attribute name="managedBean" required="true"/>
</cc:interface>

<!-- IMPLEMENTATION -->
<cc:implementation>
    <h:commandButton  id="btn_#{cc.attrs.label}" title="#{cc.attrs.tooltip}" immediate="true"
                      image="/resources/img/#{cc.attrs.img}">
        <f:ajax event="click" execute="@form" render="#{cc.attrs.render}" listener="#{cc.attrs.managedBean[cc.attrs.listener]}" />
    </h:commandButton>
</cc:implementation>
```

Comment: Please format your posts correctly. Don't use `<br>`-tags, and indent source-code examples by four spaces, or just mark them and click the `code` button above the edit field. In your text, surround code snippets (also variable-names and the likes) with ticks - ` to mark them as code. Before you hit the `Post`-button, look at the preview-field below the edit field, and check if your question looks OK.

Answer (score 1):

based on this post, [JSF 2 - How can I add an Ajax listener method to composite component interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6453842/jsf-2-how-can-i-add-an-ajax-listener-method-to-composite-component-interface) i've found a solution. The problem was the declaration of the listener attribute `cc:attribute name="listener" required="true"/>` it should be `cc:attribute name="listener" method-signature="void listener()" required="true"/>`

There is still one (in my case minor) problem as mentioned by BalusC in the previously mentioned post: I can't us the AjaxBehvaiorEvent. I'm using Netbeans 6.9.1, Gfish3.1 and Mojarra2.1.1