# f:ajax listener in composite component stopped working in WildFly 10

Tags: jsf-2.2, composite-component, wildfly-10

We have in our JSF 2.2 project a composite component used like this (the code has been simplified for clarity):

```html
<!-- the page with the composite component inside -->
<my:component methodListener="#{myBean.myMethod}" />

<!-- the composite component -->
<cc:interface>
    <cc:attribute name="methodListener" required="true" method-signature="void listener(javax.faces.event.AjaxBehaviorEvent)" />
    ...
<cc:implementation>
    <h:commandLink>
        <f:ajax listener="#{cc.attrs.methodListener}" />
        <f:attribute name="myAttribute" value="myValue" />
    </h:commandLink>
```

```java
// the called method
public void myMethod(AjaxBehaviorEvent event)
{
    System.out.println("> " + event);
}
```

In Wildfly 9.0.2, when clicking on the `commandLink` inside the composite component, `myMethod` is called and the event is defined (allowing us to find back `myAttribute` value).

**In Wildfly 10.1.0, with the exact same code, `myMethod` is called but the event parameter is always `null`.**

Are we doing something wrong here?

A tested workaround could be to replace the methodListener CC attribute with a bean instance, something like the following code. Still, this would require a lot of replacements in our project, therefore we'd like to avoid this solution.

```html
<!-- the workaround composite component -->
<cc:interface>
    <cc:attribute name="methodBean" required="true" type="com.example.myBean" />
...
<cc:implementation>
    <h:commandLink>
        <f:ajax listener="#{cc.attrs.methodBean.myMethod}" />
        <f:attribute name="myAttribute" value="myValue" />
    </h:commandLink>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I didn't see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6454339/923712) from BalusC on another related question. I still don't understand why my code worked on WF9 and broke on WF10, but here's a simple solution, where we don't have to change anything but the component itself:

```html
<!-- the CC xhtml -->
<h:commandLink>
    <f:ajax listener="#{cc.methodListener}" />
    <f:attribute name="myAttribute" value="myValue" />
</h:commandLink>
```

```java
// the CC implementation
public void methodListener(AjaxBehaviorEvent event)
{
    FacesContext context = getCurrentInstance();
    MethodExpression ajaxEventListener = (MethodExpression) getAttributes().get("methodListener");
    ajaxEventListener.invoke(context.getELContext(), new Object[] { event });
}
```